# MonacaのCordova4.1を5.2にバージョンアップしたらclose();が使えない

Tags: javascript, monaca

お世話になっております。

標題にもありますようにCordovaのバージョンアップを行ったら

```
window.close();
```

で画面が閉じれなくなりました。iPhone版は元々できずに困っていましたが、Android版でも急に動作しなくなりました。どうすれば対応できるでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

これは`InAppBrowser`の話でしょうか？
`windows`という変数は`InAppBrowser`のオブジェクトですか？
現状の環境がよくわかりませんが、`Cordovaプラグインの管理`から
一度、無効化し、有効化しなおしてはいかがでしょうか？
プラグインのバージョンが低いのかもしれません。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。確認してみます。